# How to Map many one-to-many relationship in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I have few Domain Models - `Address`, `Customer`, `Employee`, `StoreLocation`. `Address` has many to one relationship with `Customer`and `Employee` and one to one relationship with StoreLocation.

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id;
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class StoreLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}


public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

How to Map this relationship?. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and Entity Framework 4.1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using code-first (I think you want this, else, you have to edit your Q), the first way is the way explained below:

**Entities:**

```
public class Address {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual StoreLocation StoreLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class StoreLocation {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}


public class Employee {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext** inherited class:

```
public class ManyOneToManyContext : DbContext {

    static ManyOneToManyContext() {
        Database.SetInitializer<ManyOneToManyContext>(new ManyOneToManyInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreLocation> StoreLocations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasMany(c => c.Addresses).WithOptional(a => a.Customer).HasForeignKey(a => a.CustomerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StoreLocation>().HasRequired(s => s.Address).WithOptional(a => a.StoreLocation).Map(t => t.MapKey("AddressId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasMany(e => e.Addresses).WithOptional(a => a.Employee).HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId);
    }
}
```

**Context Initializer:**

```
public class ManyOneToManyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ManyOneToManyContext> {
    protected override void Seed(ManyOneToManyContext context) {

    }
}
```

That will create the db-schema below:
[image: Many one-to-many relationship]
Let me know if you have any questions or need clarifications on any part.

Comment: HI Javad_Amiry, Thanks for the answer. I always come to Stackoverflow when i have some doubts because there are many people like you help others with lots of effort. Thanks. One more Question is If I add few more entities refering Address with many to one, there will be many fields like customerid, employeeid added to the address table with many null values, is that a right DB design?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. No, I think this can't be a normal and good design. I think you have to use third-tables to assign entities. **OR** you can merge `Address` by each entity, if entities count is to much. However, this question is separated of your main Q, and you should ask it in a separated Q (because of SOF's rolls). Also, if the answer, help you to resolve the problem, please accept it. Thank you.