# How to add/update/delete child entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Work on Asp.net mvc entity framework,face problem on child entities add/update/delete portion.

[image]
Here is my relationships

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string ContactPersonPhone { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal EstamationCost { get; set; }

    public DateTime EstemateDelevaryTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Job > Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

Please take a look at my job entity,it's not contain any parent id just contain the relation ship.

Want to know how to create any entry/update/delete on child entity.I used bellow syntax for create:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(JobManageViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _unitOfWorkAsync.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                var application = model.ToDalEntity();
                application.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
                _jobService.Insert(application);
                var changes = await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
                _unitOfWorkAsync.Commit();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                // Rollback transaction
                _unitOfWorkAsync.Rollback();
            }
        }
        LoadClientsInViewData();
        return View(model);
    }


public Job ToDalEntity(Job model)
{
    model.JobId = this.JobId;
    model.JobDescription = this.JobDescription;
    model.EstamationCost = this.EstamationCost;
    model.EstemateDelevaryTime = this.EstemateDelevaryTime;

    return model;
}
```

Problem is can not insert client information on Job table.How to insert/update/delete client information on job table

Comment: If the Client class has a one-to-many relationship with the jobs class, I believe you should just have to add: int? ClientId to the job class, or use the modelbuilder in the context class:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719482/how-to-map-many-one-to-many-relationship-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Dan thanks for your reply,i dont want to use ClientId in my job table. As per your suggestion then how to modelBuilder will be write with out Job table having clientId.

Comment: Is there a reason?  The easiest way to do this with Entity Framework is a foreign key.

Using the modelBinder will create the foreign key in the table anyway.

Comment: Dan Thank you for your reply ,I am work on EntityFramework.6.1.0 ,here you no need to define the foreign key on child table,it's automatically created by the entity frame work. So i try to avoid foreign key written process as you say.Is there any way to put parent information on child table as i like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible approach, but i strongly do not recommend you to do it, because it is really a bad practice, you are going to break SOLID principles, and so on.

But you could do this way:

### Configure your relationship tables

I've created two separated classes, one for each table

**Client Configuration**

```
public class ClientEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ClientId);
        Property(x => x.ClientId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasMany(x => x.Jobs).WithOptional(x => x.Client);
    }
}
```

**Job Configuration**

```
public class JobEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    public JobEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.JobId);
        Property(x => x.JobId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasOptional(x => x.Client).WithMany(x => x.Jobs);
    }
}
```

On your context class, you set those classes as your configuration:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClientEntityTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobEntityTypeConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The trick to add your already created client to your Job entity, is that you must set a new instance of Client, and set only the Id, and then tell to your Context that this instance is already exists on database.

```
var clientAlreadyExists = new Client {ClientId = 1};
context.Clients.Attach(clientAlreadyExists);
job.Client = clientAlreadyExists;        

context.Jobs.Add(product);
```

I recommend you to use Repository Pattern, and do not access your context directly from your Controller, and one more time a say this to you, your approach **is a Bad Practice**.